# AS3 internal and custom namespaces

Tags: actionscript-3, namespaces, encapsulation

I have the following packages:

`spark`
    `spark.engine`

Within `spark` I have a class `SeCore`; and within `spark.engine` I have `SeStepper` and `SeKeyboard`.

What I'm trying to achieve is have `SeCore` as being the only class that can create an instance of `SeStepper` or `SeKeyboard`. This can be achieved by moving `SeCore` into the `spark.engine` package and making the other two classes `internal`, but I'd like to have `SeCore` in the `spark` package if possible.

I've tried making my own namespace to handle this, like so:

```
package spark.engine
{
    import spark.namespaces.spark_core;

    use namespace spark_core;

    spark_core class SeStepper extends SeObject
    {
        //
    }
}
```

However I get the error:

> **1116:** A user-defined namespace attribute can only be used at the top
>   level of a class definition.

Are there any other approaches I can take to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Is checking at runtime OK, or do you want it at compile time?

Comment: RIAstar, compile time is preferable, but runtime is alright because I can just throw an error. @Jevgenij Dmitrijev What does your comment have to do with anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% of the time, marking anything as 'internal' is a bad idea. It's better to have a naming convention for 'off-limits' classes and members, and allow developers to go there at their own risk. Marking things as 'internal' or 'private' is something that should only be done rarely, and with great forethought.

However, you could enforce this behavior at run time by using a read-only property in SeCore and checking its value from SeStepper and SeKeyboard.

Following is pseudocode, haven't used AS3 in a while.

In SeCore

```
private var _createAuthorized = false;
public function get CreateAuthorized():boolean {return _createAuthorized;}

private function createSeStepper(){
  _createAuthorized = true;
  var obj = new SeStepper(this)
  _createAuthorized = false;
  return obj;
}
```

in SeStepper

```
public function SeStepper(core:SeCore){
  if (!core.CreateAuthorized) throw new Error("Only SeCore can do this");
}
```

Comment: Re your first note: basically, I'm working on an engine where you create an instance of SeCore (which will in the constructor create instances of other classes such as the stepper and the keyboard). Access of those classes are given through core.keyboard, etc but I don't want people to make instances of them on their own. Hopefully that clears up any suggestions that my coding style is strange/problematic. Sure I could simply use a naming convention, but I'm trying to lock what shouldn't be accessed down as much as possible mainly to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I can't agree with the answer, i mean making things public is way to invite hackers. I can execute any public functions in any flash running on my computer in any context i want, i can even override their execution in memory since they are easy to find, whereas doing something like that with private/internal functions is almost impossible.

Comment: I'm open to superior answers, as your comments are what I had in mind also.